# Simple C scanf does not work?

Tags: c, console, scanf

If I try something such as:

```
int anint;
char achar;

printf("\nEnter any integer:");
scanf("%d", &anint);
printf("\nEnter any character:");
scanf("%c", &achar);
printf("\nHello\n");
printf("\nThe integer entered is %d\n", anint);
printf("\nThe char entered is %c\n", achar);
```

It allows entering an integer, then skips the second `scanf` completely, this is really strange, as when I swap the two (the `char` scanf first), it works fine. What on earth could be wrong?

Comment: your pointers have the wrong sizes, anint is a char and achar is an int.  don't do this.

Comment: @Variable Length Coder: I'm sorry about that, was paraphrasing a simpler example and mixed to the two up. That mistype is not related to my problem, fixed the example.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When reading input using `scanf`, the input is read after the return key is pressed but the newline generated by the return key is not consumed by `scanf`, which means the next time you read a `char` from standard input there will be a newline ready to be read.

One way to avoid is to use `fgets` to read the input as a string and then extract what you want using `sscanf` as:

```
char line[MAX];

printf("\nEnter any integer:");
if( fgets(line,MAX,stdin) && sscanf(line,"%d", &anint)!=1 ) 
   anint=0;

printf("\nEnter any character:");
if( fgets(line,MAX,stdin) && sscanf(line,"%c", &achar)!=1 ) 
   achar=0;
```

Another way to consume the newline would be to `scanf("%c%*c",&anint);`. The `%*c` will read the newline from the buffer and discard it.

You might want to read this:

[C FAQ : Why does everyone say not to use scanf?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: You'd need the `%*c` after the `%d` format (too, or instead), wouldn't you?  Though even that is not reliable - if the user typed a space or something after the number and before the newline.  I think `fgets()` + `sscanf()` is better.

Comment: @Jonathan: You are right. We would need it after the `%d`. And yes `fgets + sscanf` is always better.

Comment: @codeaddict: Sorry for lengthy accept, but you really did give me some more insight on how the internals work in C. I really appreciate the C FAQ link too, all the better to be wise to teach new people these things, if I ever get to help people out later on.

Comment: /*Take char input using scanf after int input using scanf just use fflush(stdin) function */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int x;
  char y;
  clrscr();
  printf(" enter an int ");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  fflush(stdin);
  printf("\n Now enter a char");
  scanf("%c",&y);
  printf("\n X=%d and Y=%c",x,y);
  getch();
}

Answer (score 20):

The other answers are correct - `%c` does not skip whitespace.  The easiest way to make it do so is to place whitespace before the `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c", &achar);
```

(Any whitespace in the format string will make `scanf` consume all consecutive whitespace).

Comment: How exactly does skipping the whitespace helps with discarding the newline? For example: `scanf("\n%c", &achar);` would work too.

Comment: @cpx: Because a newline is whitespace.  Any whitespace in the format string behaves like any other whitespace, so `\n` is just as good as a space (but one more letter).

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't skip the second `scanf()`; the second `scanf()` reads the newline left behind by the first `scanf()`.  Most format codes skip white space; the `%c` format does not skip white space.

Answer (score 3):

calling `getchar()` before `scanf` will also purge the stored line break. More lightweight but more situational

```
char input_1;
char input_2;
getchar();
scanf("%c", &input_1);
getchar();
scanf("%c", &input_2);
```

will flush the line breaks, more useful in consecutive lines of code where you know it's only one queued value and not a string

Comment: getchar solves it, helped me tutor my sister on her programming class.

Answer (score 0):

Try also _flushall() after each printf call. . Basically, by default MS’s C++ buffers stream output, and the the flushing causes the output stream to empty.