# C Scanf suddenly stopped reading in values

Tags: c, integer, printf, scanf

I'm trying to run a simple C program on my Mac. It worked fine for a while but then suddenly scanf stopped working. I basically want to read in an integer value and output what was entered. No matter the integer I enter the program keeps outputting 0. I've tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work) but nothing works. I've tried running the program in both terminal and xcode but still nothing. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int numberOfElements = 0;
  scanf("Number of elements: %d",&numberOfElements);
  printf("%d\n",numberOfElements); //keeps returning 0 no matter the number I enter
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember to check the return value from `scanf()` (or any of that family of functions).  It would be returning 0 unless you type `Number of elements: 23456` or something similar.  In fact, you need to check (practically) every input operation to make sure it worked correctly.  Assuming it worked will lead to problems, sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include any non-format characters into `scanf/fscanf/sscanf` format string, it means that you *require* these characters to be present in the input stream (or input string, in case of `sscanf`). If these characters are not present in the input, `scanf` fails. Space character has special meaning though, causing `scanf` to skip all whitespace, but not requiring any whitespace to be present.

So, in order for this `scanf` to succeed

```
scanf("Number of elements: %d", &numberOfElements);
```

you have to enter, literally

```
Number of elements: 10
```

or

```
Numberof    elements:10
```

or

```
Numberofelements:    10
```

or something like that. I.e. you have to type in the words `Number`, `of`, `elements` and the `:` as well. If you just enter `10`, the `scanf` will fail, since a mere `10` does not match the requested format.

I'm sure this was not your intent. What you really wanted to do, apparently, is to print the prompt using `printf` and then do a simple

```
scanf("%d", &numberOfElements);
```

The aforementioned feature of `scanf` could be useful, but probably only in some rare cases. This means that when you see any non-format text in `scanf` format string, there's a good possibility that something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses, all the answers are correct. AudreyT just gave a bit more insight into the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to print the prompt, and only scan the input:

```
printf("Number of elements: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &numberOfElements);
```

Generally, it is better to avoid using `scanf()` directly. Instead, you can obtain a line of input and then use `sscanf()` on the retrieved string for better control of errors.

```
char line[MAX_LINE];
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &numberOfElements) != 1) {
        printf("You didn't input a number: %s", line);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not require `fflush` just prior to `scanf`.  The output buffer is flushed by `scanf`.

Comment: @unxnut: I don't see any documentation describing that flush behavior for `scanf()`. Is it a POSIX thing?

Answer (score 3):

You should not have `Number of elements:` in the `scanf` statement.  You want to change the `scanf` statement to:

```
printf ( "Number of elements: " );
scanf ("%d", &numberOfElements );
```

Comment: Not keen on the amount of space around the parentheses...it is a style issue, but it is not conventional.  Look at K&R or the C standard.