# Do-While loop in C

Tags: c

I recently started working with C programming language, about two or three days ago, but I encountered some problem when working with the do-while loop, This is part of my program that would not run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){        
    char another_game   =   'Y';
    scanf("%c", &another_game);
    do{
        printf("\nWould you like to continue(Y/N)?");
        scanf("%c", &another_game);
    }while(toupper(another_game) == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

The loop  is suppose to continue running as long as the user types `'Y'` or `'y'` when prompt to do so, but I noticed that after the program executes the loop the first time it just displays the question again and  then the loop breaks. I tried using integers, for the user to type `1` when he wishes to continue or `0` when he wishes to quit, it worked, so I do not understand why this one would not. I would appreciate all help on solving this issue, thanks

Comment: `scanf("%c",...)` doesn't consume the newline. Your confirmation gets that newline. Use `scanf(" %c", &another_game);` to skip initial whitespace. (it's a duplicate many times, but I'm too lazy to search. Any takers?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple C scanf does not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work)

Comment: @robmayoff, sorry please, I am not asking why scanf does not work, I am asking why my program does not work. Thank you

Comment: after scanf use flushall();
refer [link]http://www.phanderson.com/C/scanf.html

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Titles are wrong (as so many times on SO). That question **is** a dupe.

Comment: James, your program does not work because you are using `scanf` incorrectly.  You do not understand what `scanf` is doing.

Comment: @robmayoff, thanks I now understand why it did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you press `<enter>`, there's the trailing newline character in the stdin buffer. Better use `fgets()` instead:

```
char buf[0x10];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
if (toupper(buf[0]) == 'Y') {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how do I eliminate the trailing line from scanf, i mean if there is a way to eliminate it

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge I think Daniel Fischer's comment sums it up, but you should **really avoid using `scanf()`.** Its usage is less than unintuitive, and it's very easy to get it wrong, especially for a beginner. I don't use it either. I fear it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use getchar as it would be more deterministic for your purposes.  Also be sure to add one more getchar to check for newline character.

`do {
printf("enter Y/N\n");
} while( ( (toupper(getchar()) == 'Y') + (getchar() == '\n') ) == 2);`