# Scanf function not accepting input

Tags: c, scanf

I am working on a simple C program using a struct named 'student'. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
  struct  student {
    char name[50];
    int id;
    float marks_1;
    float marks_2;

};


void main(){

    int num,a,i;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    struct student s[num];
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        a=i+1;
        printf("Enter name of student number %d\n",a);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s[i].name);

    }

  }
```

When I run the program I am able to enter the number of students correctly, but after that I am not able to enter the name corresponding to each student. This is the output that I get.

```
Enter number of students
2
Enter name of student number 1
Enter name of student number 2

RUN FINISHED; exit value 2; real time: 1s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

What might be the problem? Any help appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work trythis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s[i].name);` to `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",s[i].name);`. Notice the space given before specifier to consume last input char left in stdin.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

leaves the newline you typed to send the input to the programme in the input buffer. Thus the first iteration of

```
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    a=i+1;
    printf("Enter name of student number %d\n",a);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s[i].name);

}
```

immediately finds that newline and scans in an empty string.

Consume the newline before scanning, either by changing the first format to `"%d%*c"` or by adding a space to the start of the name-scanning format to skip initial white space.

Answer (score 2):

> Scanf function not accepting input

If `scanf()` doesn't work, then use `fgets()`:

```
fgets(s[i].name, sizeof(s[i].name), stdin);
```

And stay far away from `scanf()` if/while you don't have a full, proper understanding of how it works, because it's not intuitive to use, so to say. (It's also unsafe if you are not careful enough, and in this case, you weren't. The code is prone to buffer overflows.)

Comment: @fts It **is** working. Perhaps you should use it *appropriately.* Also, "not working" is not descriptive at all. How **exactly** isn't it working?

Comment: @H2CO3  `fgets()` would put the `\n` in `s[i].name`.

Comment: @chux Yes, it would. And then you write `*strchr(s[i].name, '\n') = 0;`, and **kaboom** it's gone. `fgets()` is still superior to `scanf()` when it comes to getting user input.

Comment: @H2CO3 Agree about `fgets()` superiority.  The answer, as posted, would be better including your recommended post-`fgets()` processing.

Comment: @chux But I feel, it wouldn't, unfortunately. New users' attitude after they got a quick'n'dirty-but-works-solution: "thanks, it works perfectly, I never come back to this question anymore!"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s[i].name);
```

but try replacing it with:

```
scanf("%50[^\n]s",s[i].name);
```

Comment: That's for scanning a string with no newlines in it.

Comment: @tim I want to include white spaces too in my 'name'. Eg. if I enter 'My Name' and then print the result I get 'My' and not 'My Name'.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know any student whose name contains newlines :p

Comment: @fts it does return "My Name" ;)

Comment: @TimvanElsloo But surely you know students whose name contains spaces? `"%s"` stops at the first whitespace it finds after skipping initial whitespace.

Comment: @TimvanElsloo Non sequitur. `%s` scans only until the first whitespace. Some people think that it's a good idea to tell `scanf()` to scan up to the first newline. (It isn't, but still.)

Comment: The `s` in `"%50[^\n]s"` serves no purpose.  The format specifier ends with the `]`.

Answer (score 0):

to read a line in c that include white spaces use `fgets (name, 100, stdin);`

here is the full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
  struct  student {
    char name[50];
    int id;
    float marks_1;
    float marks_2;

};


void main(){

    int num,a,i;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    struct student s[num];
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        a=i+1;
        printf("Enter name of student number %d\n",a);
        fgets (s[i].name, 50, stdin);

    }

  }
```

`scanf` will read until the first whitespace, but not `fgets`, however, if you'll press enter when using `fgets` it'll will be stored in the string as well. so you need to remove it afterwards