# char Input in C by scanf

Tags: c, char, scanf

Help me Please.
I want to know why it happen.

This code is not give right answer:

```
#include < stdio.h>

int main()

{

  char c,ch;

  int i;

    printf("Welcome buddy!\n\nPlease input first character of your name: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    printf("\nPlease input first character of your lovers name: ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);

    printf("\nHow many children do you want? ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    printf("\n\n%c loves %c and %c want %d children",c,ch,c,i);

  return 0;
}
```

---

but this code give right answer.

```
#include < stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c,ch;
  int i;

    printf("Welcome buddy!\n\nPlease input first character of your name: ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);

    printf("\nPlease input first character of your lovers name: ");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);

    printf("\nHow many children do you want? ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    printf("\n\n%c loves %c and %c want %d children",c,ch,c,i);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Why?
and How?

Please help me anyone who know this why it happend.

Comment: I think the second answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3745117/1322972) will probably be helpful. Especially the part about "skips whitespace"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you are giving like this, It will not ignore the white spaces.

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

When you are giving the input to the first `scanf` then you will give the `enter('\n')`. It is one character so it will take that as input to the second `scanf`. So second input will not get input from the user.

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

If you give like this, then it will ignore that white space character, then it will ask for the input from the user.

Answer (score 2):

The first program doesn't work properly, because the scanf function when checking for input doesn't remove automatically whitespaces when trying to parse characters.
So in the first program the value of `c` will be a char and the value of `ch` will be the `'\n'` (newline) char. 
Using `scanf("\n%c", &varname);` or `scanf(" %c", &varname);` will parse the newline inserted while pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

The **scanf** function reads data from standard input stream **stdin**.

**int scanf(const char *format, …);**
The white-space characters in *format*, such as blanks and new-line characters, causes scanf to read, but not store, all consecutive white-space characters in the input up to the next character that is not a white-space character.

Now, when you press, by example, "a" and "return", you have two chars in the **stdin** stream: a and the \n char.
That is why the second call to scanf assign the \n char to ch var.

Comment: Thank you. I have not so much idea about stdin. I'll learn about stdin now.

Answer (score 0):

your scanf() function takes input from **stdin**. Now when you hit any character from keyboard and hit enter, character entered by you is scanned by scanf() but still enter is present in **stdin** which will be scanned by scanf() below it. To ignore white spaces you have to use scanf() with " %c".

Comment: Thank you. I have not so much idea about stdin. I'll read about stdin now.