# Can someone tell me why this program keeps crashing?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Maybe I'm still tired, but I can't seem to figure out why this keeps crashing after the second input. No point in sorting it if it keeps breaking before the values are entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5

int main(){

  int input[MAX], output[MAX], i, j, high;

  printf("Please enter 5 exam scores.\n");
  for (i=0; i<MAX; i++){
      scanf("%d\n", input[i]);
  }
  for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
      printf("%d\n", input[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the debugger can tell you why. Compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) then  **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: BTW, `MAX` is a commonly used macro name. I recommend using something different and longer, perhaps `MY_DIM`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &input[i]);` And for future working on `scanf()` if you use `%c` add leading space in it, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you forgot to put '&' before input[i]:

```
scanf("%d\n", input[i]);
///          ^    missing &
```

Comment: Yup, definitely still tired then. Thanks a ton. Been staring at it for the past 15 minutes for something simple. Probably should go back to sleep.

Comment: Remove `\n` from it