# Unknown characters being displayed while printing character array

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I'm creating a Caesar cipher in C and I'm having an issue when displaying the encoded message. It works if the message consists of very few characters but as soon as the message exceeds a certain amount of characters the **printf** function begins to display unknown characters which I assume are junk bytes. Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    /*
        Remember to free allocated memory
    */
    char *result;
    if((result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1)) != NULL)
    {
        result[0] = '\0';
        strcat(result, s1);
        strcat(result, s2);
    }

    return result;
}

void encode(const char *alpha, const char *message)
{
    char result[(sizeof(message) / sizeof(char))];
    int x, y, z;

    memset(result, '\0', sizeof(result));
    for(x = 0; x < strlen(message); x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 25; y++)
        {
            if(alpha[y] == message[x])
            {
                z = (y + 3);
                if(z > 25)
                {
                    z = z % 25;
                }

                result[x] = alpha[z];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", result);

    //return result;
}

int main()
{
    char message[200];
    char *result;
    char array[26] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    printf("Input your message:");
    scanf("%s", &message);

    encode(array, message);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `scanf("%s", &message);` is wrong. Should be `scanf("%s", message);`

Comment: Just corrected that, thank you. I'm pretty new to C

Comment: Try not to call strlen in a loop for(x = 0; x < strlen(message); x++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
char result[(sizeof(message) / sizeof(char))];
```

to

```
char result[strlen(message) + 1];
```

This leaves room in your buffer for a [terminating null-character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). `sizeof` also can ont be used to get the length of c-strings, we need to use `strlen` for this. You will need to update the `memset` call as well.

`sizeof` is used by the compiler, so in this case you will ask your compiler "what is the size of `message`", which in this case will be 8 (assuimg 64-bit), because a pointer is 8 bytes.

Other than that you should be careful with `scanf`, it is fine as it is now because you read one line of input, but if you tried reading one more line you might [run into trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work).

As mentioned in the comments, `for(x = 0; x < strlen(message); x++)` runs `strlen` once per loop iteration, adding a rather big extra load on your program, that grows exponentially as the length of `message` increases.

Your `concat` function is unused, unsure why you included it?

Comment: Ah, my fault for forgetting the allocated space for the null byte terminator, thank you.

Comment: @JosephHarris The null byte isn't the problem.  The problem is you're taking the size of a pointer, which is probably 4 or 8 and completely independent of the how long the string is.

Comment: Ah so sizeof will only return the size of the actual pointer and in order to find the actual length of the string strlen is suitable.

Comment: I was tampering with it and then I realised it wasn't useful but hadn't yet removed it.

Comment: you might want to correct this memset as well memset(result, '\0', sizeof(result));

Comment: `sizeof` is not evaluated by the preprocessor.  It gets evaluated during the actual compilation.