# searching for a character throughout 4 strings in c using strchr

Tags: c, character, scanf, strchr

I'm having some trouble figuring out why when I run the program it won't let me scan the character I want to search for. It just jumps straight to the last printf statement.

```
int main()
{
char s1[100], s2[100], s3[100], s4[100];
char character
char *charSearch[3] = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
int counter = 0;
int i;

printf("Enter 4 lines of text: \n");
scanf("%s %s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3, &s4);
printf("Enter a any character to search:\n");

scanf("%c", &character);

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
while(charSearch[i] = strchr(  charSearch, character ))
{
counter++;
charsearch[i]++;
}
}
printf("Total occurrences of character %c is %d", character, counter);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent our code

Comment: Also note that `%s` reads a string terminated by whitespace, which is not at all what I would call a "line of text", so your users may easily be confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First things first, you declared an array of `char pointers` of size `3` while giving it `4` elements :
`char *charSearch[3] = {s1, s2, s3, s4};`

This should be : `char *charSearch[4] = {s1, s2, s3, s4};`
This declaration should also be done after scanning the contents of the 4 `char` array `{s1,s2,s3,s4}` and not before.

---

The name of any array is a `pointer` to its first element, thus when using `scanf()` with `char` arrays, you already pass the desired address by doing so : `scanf("%s %s %s %s", s1, s2, s3, s4);`

What you did here : `scanf("%s %s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3, &s4);` passed the address of the first address (sounds weird I know xD).

---

There is also that irritating bug with `scanf("%c", &character);` which if you've previously scanned anything ending with a `new line`, the character will take this `\n` as its input. To over come this, it should be written as : `scanf(" %c", &character);`

---

Now to `strchr()`, this functions takes two parameters, a `char` `pointer`to a string and the character to search for in the string and it returns another `char` `pointer` to the location of the character if it was found and `NULL` otherwise.

We'll need to do the following instead:

```
char *ptr = strchr( charSearch[i], character );
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        ptr = strchr( ptr+1, character );
        counter++;
    }
```

What it does is that at the beginning of each iteration of the `for` loop, it declares a `char` `pointer` and initialize it to the return value of the `strchr()` function. Then we loop while this `pointer` is not equal to `NULL` and in each iteration increment our counter and our `pointer` to make it pointing to the next character in the string.

---

The final working version of your code should look like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char s1[100], s2[100], s3[100], s4[100];
char character;
int counter = 0;
int i;

printf("Enter 4 lines of text: \n");
scanf("%s %s %s %s", s1, s2, s3, s4);
char *charSearch[4] = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
printf("Enter a any character to search:\n");

scanf(" %c", &character);

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    char *ptr = strchr( charSearch[i], character );
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        ptr = strchr( ptr+1, character );
    counter++;
    }
}
printf("Total occurrences of character %c is %d\n", character, counter);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MariaGreenfield anytime ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when reading input using `scanf`, the input is read after the return key is pressed but the newline generated by the return key is not consumed by `scanf`, which means the next time you read a char from standard input there will be a newline ready to be read.

Source : [Simple C scanf does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

A Russian hacker will help you.:)

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Try not to use magic numbers. The compiler shall issue a diagnostic message relative to this declaration

```
char *charSearch[3] = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
```

because there are more initializers than elements in the array.

This statement with `scanf` is unsafe and moreover the argument expressions are invalid.

```
scanf("%s %s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3, &s4);
```

It is desirable to place a blank in the format specifier in this statement

```
scanf("%c", &character);
      ^^^^
```

Otherwise blank characters (as for example the new ,line character) can be read.

The condition in the while statement does not make sense

```
while(charSearch[i] = strchr(  charSearch, character ))
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main( void )
{
    char s1[SIZE], s2[SIZE], s3[SIZE], s4[SIZE];
    char * charSearch[] = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof(charSearch) / sizeof(*charSearch);
    char character;

    size_t counter = 0;

    printf( "Enter %zu lines of text: \n", N );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        charSearch[i][0] = '\0';
        fgets(charSearch[i], SIZE, stdin);
    }

    printf("Enter any character to search:\n");

    scanf(" %c", &character );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (char *p = charSearch[i]; ( p = strchr(p, character) ) != NULL; ++p )
        {
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    printf("Total occurrences of character %c is %zu\n", character, counter);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter 4 lines of text:
Hello World
How are you?
Stackoverflow
I'm learning C
Enter any character to search:
e
Total occurrences of character e is 4
```