# C programming while loop not asking for input

Tags: c, scanf

Why while loop is exiting without asking for the value of another, even in the for loop the value of another is not being set .

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
            char another ='y';
            int num = 0;
            int i =0;
            /*for(;another =='y'||another =='Y';i++){
                    scanf("%d",&num);
                    printf("%d",num);
                    printf("Enter another num?");
                    scanf("%c",&another);
            }*/
            while(another == 'y'|| another == 'Y'){
                    scanf("%d",&num);
                    printf("%d",num);
                    if(another == 'y'||another =='Y')
                            scanf("%c",&another);
            }
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&another);`-->`scanf(" %c",&another);` (mind the space )

Comment: You must check the value returned by `scanf()` to know whether `num` got set to a value.  The UI design isn't very elegant, either.  The user could type `12y13y14y15n` and the code would sort of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input `num`, it leaves behind newline `\n` character. The second `scanf()` reads the newline left behind by the first `scanf()`.

Hence your program doesn't wait for your input `another` as it already received `\n` as the input which will lead to exit of your `while` loop.

To fix this, change:

```
scanf("%c",&another);
```

To:

```
scanf(" %c",&another);
```

Note the leading whitespace in the format string `" %c"` will make scanf consume the newline character thereby fixing your problem.

Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work/3744788#3744788) for more such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Just put fflush(stdin) before scanf() line. And Include stdlib.h header file.

Comment: Flushing stdin is implementation specific at best.

Comment: Sry but I can't understand what you say. @Yunnosch

Comment: Flushing is only defined for outputs, not for input. If your environment does anything seemingly reliable and useful when you flush your input, then it is just that: Your environment (i.e. not necessarily any other) only seems to do something useful and might not even do it reliably.