# Program ends suddenly, with switch case inside while loop in C

Tags: c, function, while-loop, switch-statement

I have this program show, which allows me to display a menu with 3 choices. If you choose anything except exit (0) then the program continues to loop.

However, when I try to call a function from inside the switch statement, once the function is finished, the loop exists completely. I want to go back to the menu and continue unless I select exit.

The program works, without the function call. 
It also works if I select 2, triangle, it then stays in the loop.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it,

many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int rows;

void xmasTree(void)
{ 
 printf("Enter Rows:\n>");
 scanf("%d",&rows);
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int flag = 1;
    while (flag)
    {
        //Print menu
        printf("1: Create xmas tree\n");
        printf("2: Create triangle\n");
        printf("0: exit\n");
        printf("Enter choice :");
        //read input
        char buffer[10];
        fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
        //convert to number
        int number = atoi (buffer);

        //work on input
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Building your xmas tree\n");
                xmasTree();
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("creating your triangle\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                flag = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("INVAID INPUT\n");
                break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it print "Exiting..."? Are you running your program from within Eclipse?

Comment: That's because of the scanf. The newline is not consumed so you'll `atoi('\n')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work

Comment: I suspect the `scanf("%d",&rows);` having datas keps in the buffer, intercepted by `fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);` which will provide 0 to `int number = atoi (buffer);` (because `atoi()` returns 0 if it can't convert to int

Comment: regarding: `int rows;`  and `scanf("%d",&rows);`  Since `rows` is never used, this results in a warning from the compiler.

Comment: regarding: `int main (int argc, char ** argv)`  since the parameters are not used, the compiler outputs two warning messages.  To avoid the warning messages, Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`:  `int main( void )`

Comment: when calling functions like: `scanf()` and `fgets()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that here

```
scanf("%d",&rows);
```

you read a number from `stdin`, but you *leave the trailing newline*  inside the stream!

Then, in the next loop iteration

```
fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
```

reads the (empty) line and

```
int number = atoi (buffer);
```

sets `number` to `0`, causing your program to exit.

One possible fix would be to read in `rows` with `fgets()` and `atoi()` as you do it with `number`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this call in the function `xmasTree`

```
scanf("%d",&rows);
```

After it there is stored the new line character `'\n'` in the buffer. So the next call of the function `fgets` reads an empty string. You should remove this new line character as for example

```
scanf("%d",&rows);
scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
scanf( "%*c" );
```